# Having trouble finding elements in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, inspect-element

Haven't done serious JavaScript since 90s, so looks like a couple of things changed.  I am trying to debug a page (i didn't write it).  So in Chrome, I right-click on an element and select Inspect Element.  It brings me to an element that looks like this:

```
<div class="divRte" style="height:100px; width:200px">...</div>
```

Easy enough, I think.  Then open up the page source (in browser) and there is no mention of divRte anywhere.

Where can I find it?  Where is it?

Comment: It's possible that the element was created via javascript and is not part of the page's source. What exactly do you need to do with the `<div>` once you've found it?

Comment: Is the page written with a language that does server-side code such as PHP?  Many times developers will dynamically create elements using counters, server side code, or the like.  More detail, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you see in "View source" is the html that browser got from the server. BUT, that is not the source as the browser SEES it. When you make changes in DOM structure with JS, they don't appear in the view source. That's why you use firebug, which shows the exact DOM structure that browser sees at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

It was obviously added there is the javascript. so you wont see it in the source doc